# searching for a programming platform with hot code swap

Tags: versioning, virtual-machine, hotswap

I'm currently brainstorming over the idea how to upgrade a program while it is running. (Not while debugging, a "production" system.)

But one thing that is required for it, is to actually submit the changed source code or compiled byte code into the running process.

Pseudo Code

```
var method = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("Method1");
var content = //get it from a database (bytecode or source code)
  SELECT content FROM methods WHERE id=? AND version=?
method.SetContent(content);
```

At first, I want to achieve the system to work without the complexity of object-orientation. That leads to the following requirements:

- change source code or byte code of function
- drop functions
- add new functions
- change the signature of a function

With .NET (and others) I could inject a class via an IoC and could thus change the source code. But the loading would be cumbersome, because everything has to be in an Assembly or created via Emit.
Maybe with Java this would be easier? The whole ClassLoader is replacable, I think.

With JavaScript I could achieve many of the goals.
Simply eval a new function (MyMethod_V25) and assign it to MyClass.prototype.MyMethod.
I think one can also drop functions somehow with "del"

Which general-purpose platform can handle such things?

Answer (score 3):

In Java, you have the [OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/Main/HomePage) project, which facilitates upgrading and changing modules of your application without touching other modules.

If you don't mind learning something different, the [Erlang](http://erlang.org/) programming language was designed from the ground up with this type of application in mind.

Answer (score 3):

I think any image-based language would support this.  I know Common Lisp does, since it's probably one of the most common ways to deploy Lisp web apps, but I suspect it would work pretty much the same in, say, Smalltalk.

Answer (score 2):

Most of dynamic languages have this capability. Take a look at Ruby: you can modify existing methods etc. at runtime. When IronRuby is out, you will be able to do this also in .Net platform.

Comment: Tcl is another language where this is pretty simple.

Comment: Ruby is indeed a dynamic language -- if you have the console open you can redefine methods. However, it is not clear to me how you would do this in practice... For example, if you are running Mongrel as a web server... how would you get access to an in-process shell?

Answer (score 2):

My impression is that right now Erlang is very visible as a language which has this capability.  That said, my father-in-law (a master programmer, in my opinion) has told me that he's implemented hot-swappable code on a somewhat older platform -- assembler for what they now call z/OS (OS/390 before that).

Personally, I've been looking for ways to do this in the Java space, where the vast majority of my professional work is currently done.  In Javaland, the best publicized effort to provide hot-unloading (as far as I know) is the work done by the [OSGi Alliance](http://www.osgi.org/About/WhatIsOSGi).  That said, this solution necessarily involves some classloader magic because of how some common Java libraries are architected (example: JDBC `DriverManager`).  If you choose to go down the OSGI route, your code will likely require extensive auditing and testing to ensure that it will be usable with the OSGi architecture.

As an alternative to implementing hot-swappable code, perhaps you could implement a system which appears to have this capability using the potentially simpler mechanism of request queueing.  For example, if you need to hot-swap the piece of your system which processes large, backend requests, why not send these requests through an intermediary which can dispatch them to the backend component if it is running and accumulate them in a queue if the component is down?  This might allow you to upgrade the backend component independently of the rest of your system without redeploying as we say in the industry "the whole shebang".

Answer (score 1):

With JavaScript it can be done. Whats amazing is that Google's V8 engine is open source and is easy to implement into any C++ program.

http://code.google.com/p/v8/

Of course you will have to write a bit of a library to have functionality exposed and loading of the script from inside the JavaScript. It will depend on what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 1):

> But one thing that is required for it, is to actually submit the changed source code or compiled byte code into the running process.
>   Which general-purpose platform can handle such things?

Erlang was already mentioned, and it uses explicit "synchronization points" where a running routine may explicitly update itself by doing a "self" call using "?MODULE:routine()."

This is another important thing to keep in mind: you don't just need the capability in the VM to replace running code, but the running code also needs a way to respond to such updates and adjust accordingly.

You may also want to look into [UpgradeJ](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-716.pdf) which is a language that was specifically designed with this requirement (code hot swapping) mind.

Answer (score 0):

Erlang can do everything you are looking for, and it doesn't rely on any bolt-on libraries (unless you count OTP in that category) or coding work-arounds.  It can maintain state (i.e. "values of variables" in imperative-language-speak) across the reload, and does not require transactions to be buffered or retransmitted.  If you write your code in the OTP style then you can have your application programmers write straightforward sequential code that will have some degree of ability to execute in parallel, and to support hot reload, and all this without themhaving to worry about the details of how it's done.  It just works.

Answer (score 0):

With .NET this is perfectly implemented via the Managed Extensibility Framework. This framework is introduced in .NET 4. You can build extensible applications. It does what an IoC container could do, although it can do on thing more. It can discover functionality which does not know a priori. Additionally you can update functionality, you do not know that is going to be updated a priori. In other words, it is a framework for modular applications, whether you want to hot swap code chunks and want to provide different functionality, or update already existing.